# Divide changes/commits from one branch into two branches

Tags: git

I have a branch with two commits with two different changes.  I have to divide these changes into two branches, because only the changes from the second commit are to be merged into the main branch at the moment, the changes from the first commit have to wait. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the commit order:

- **scenario 1**: if the most recent commit should go in a separate branch, you can:

  - create a tmp branch
  - reset your dev branch to the previous commit (the one which should be merged to main)
  - merge dev to main
- **scenario 2**: if the most recent commit should be merged to main (and its previous commit should *not*)

  - make a git rebase -i @~2
  - swap the two commits
  - then follow the steps from scenario 1

From scenario 1:

```
git switch -c tmp dev
git switch -C dev dev@~1
git switch main

# then re-include tmp to dev, and go on working on dev with both commits
git merge dev
git switch dev
git merge tmp
git branch -d tmp
```